# How to write sql query to get this result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had two tables as below:

| request_id | update_from_id | sw_ref_number | raised_by_user_id | raised_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 2019-08-29 15:08:16.000 |

| id | request_id | input_id | value | is_deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 1 | 1 | 00001 | 0 |
| 22 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 75 | 2 | 1 | 00002 | 0 |
| 76 | 2 | 2 |  | 0 |

My query is:

```
select req.request_id,
       req.sw_ref_number,
       reqDet.[value] , 
       reqDet.input_id 
FROM   SOF.tblSOFRequest req  
       left join SOF.tblSOFRequestDetails reqDet 
              on req.request_id = reqDet.request_id  
where  reqDet.input_id = 1 
or     reqDet.input_id = 2
```

And after that my result is:

| request_id | sw_ref_number | value | input_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 00001 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 00002 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |  | 2 |

I want a result as:

| request_id | sw_ref_number | epi_db_no | manuf_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 00001 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 00002 |  |

Here `input_id = 1` means epi_db_no and `input_id = 2` means manuf_no.

How can I get this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using self-join like the following query.

```
SELECT req.request_id
    ,req.sw_ref_number
    ,reqDet.[value] AS epi_db_no
    ,reqDet2.[value] AS manuf_no
FROM SOF.tblSOFRequest req
LEFT JOIN SOF.tblSOFRequestDetails reqDet ON req.request_id = reqDet.request_id
LEFT JOIN SOF.tblSOFRequestDetails reqDet2 ON reqDet.request_id = reqDet2.request_id
    AND reqDet2.input_id = 2
WHERE reqDet.input_id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a simple pivot. I use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT req.request_id,
       req.sw_ref_number,
       MAX(CASE reqDet.input_id WHEN 1 THEN reqDet.[value] END) AS epi_db_no,
       MAX(CASE reqDet.input_id WHEN 2 THEN reqDet.[value] END) AS manuf_no
FROM SOF.tblSOFRequest req 
     JOIN SOF.tblSOFRequestDetails reqDet ON req.request_id = reqDet.request_id
WHERE reqDet.input_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY req.request_id,
         req.sw_ref_number;
```